# microservices use a lot of common data, what should I do?

Tags: architecture, microservices

There are a number of microservices, soon there will be much more of them, around 30. More than half of them use general data, and not directories, but really huge tables.

The data is stored in postgres, and only 1 service changes, others read.

I know that you can use CDC, but the volume is quite large, here and in Kafka a lot of space will be occupied and the table will be duplicated many times. In addition, there is a chance of tables diverging, even by 1 row, it may already be critical.

Using the API of the service to get data is also not an option, since heavy queries with a lot of joins are created. If you do this, the services will be much slower, and also consume a lot of CPU.

I thought to divide the services at the schema level in postgres.
Then make it so that microservices have the right to read the table from the master microservice schema, which writes fills the table.

But here I can't fully understand whether this will violate the principle of microservice architecture or not, because the table is used as a cache or directory.

Answer (score 0):

In case of microservices the data ownership concept means the following: all data manipulation of a given dataset should go through a single well-defined API. This does not prevent you to grant direct access to the dataset for other services.

As always there are many factors that you should put into the account whenever you considering to allow direct access to a dataset:

- Is your database cluster setup in a way that there is a write node and many read replica?
- How often the data is changing?
- Does the related data owner perform any transformation on its retrieval APIs?
- Can you define separate identities for each service which would like to directly access data?

  - (*In case of service compromise this can reduce the blast radius*)
- Can you impose different throttling rules per identity in order to avoid connection abuse and starvation?

  - (*Different access patterns might require different throttling rules*)
- etc..

---

For more information about this topic I would highly recommend to read the [Monolith to Microservices book's 4th Chapter](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/monolith-to-microservices/9781492047834/ch04.html).